# Xamarin Forms with Xamarin Player OAuth2 NInterpretException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.auth, xamarin-live-player

I'm currently on developing some little application for iOS and Android. Therefore I need an OAuth2 authentication.

**How I proceeded (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth))**

1. Create a new Xamarin.Forms project from the templates with the default Item and About page
2. Add Dependency for `Xamarin.Auth`
3. Use the button on the about page to trigger a function with the following:

   ```
           var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                                                   "CLIENTID"
                                                   ,
                                                   "SCOPE",
                                                   new
                                                       Uri("AUTH_URL"),
                                                   new Uri("REDIRECT_URL)
                                                   null,
                                                   true);
   ```
4. Add the iOS initializer in the AppDelegate.cs `global::Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.XamarinIOS.AuthenticationConfiguration.Init();`
5. Add the URL Types in `Info.plist`

I'm using the Xamarin Live Player to deploy this on my iPhone 7. When I'm triggering the button, I get the following error message:
`Uncaught Exception: Bad convert with overflow instruction 'IL_0001: conv.ovf.i.un' (NInterpretExcetion)`

Some ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Report it as an issue at http://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/ and directly deploy/debug to your iOS device without using Xamarin.Live

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm developing on windows and don't have a mac available, so unfortunately I'm not able to test this..

Comment: @SushiHangover I was able to test the app with Android and there it's working properly. So the issue occurs because of the Xamarin Live Player