# Xamarin Forms OAuth2 Error Target of Invoke is null

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth, xamarin-live-player

After solving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446286/xamarin-forms-with-xamarin-player-oauth2-ninterpretexception) problem I ran into another.

I changed the NuGet-package and implemented everything as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth).

I also added the initialization code in the `AppDelegate.cs`. But if I push the button to login I get the following error message: `Uncaught Exception: Target of Invoke is null (NullReferenceException)`.

**What I've done so far:**

- Create OAuth2Authenticator with appropriate values
- Add Event handler authenticator.Completed += OnAuthCompleted;`
- Initialized platform specific login UI with `global::Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.XamarinIOS.AuthenticationConfiguration.Init();` and `global::Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.XamarinAndroid.AuthenticationConfiguration.Init(this, bundle);`

  - Triggered the login with:

    `` var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
    presenter.Login(authenticator);` ``

I'm using the Xamarin Live Player to deploy this on my iPhone.

Some ideas how to fix this?

**UPDATE:**
I was able to test the app with a Android emulator and there is everything working. So my assumption is that it's because of the Xamarin Live Player.

Comment: *"implemented everything as described here"* does not help that much. Could you add your exact code (or at least a [mcve])?

Comment: @PaulKertscher thaks for you hint. I added the code I've added so far.